# How to tell if my starter is the problem

Tags: honda, starting, civic

I have a 2008 Honda Civic. My battery was replaced last year. Yesterday my wife tried to start the car. All the lights everything turned on except the car would not start. Not even a sound just turn the key and lights, air, radio but no sound from the starter or engine.

Comment: Although you got a new battery recently, I would strongly suggest checking it at an autoparts store. The starter and ignition system tends to draw quite a bit of power.

Answer (score 1):

Does the car have an alarm system or system which disables the ignition ... usually tied in with a key fob? If so, this is usually tied in with the Body Control Module (BCM), which if bad, could be disabling your starter. Everything else might come on, but you turn the key and nothing. You'd also see a security light on the dash board with this problem.